# Issue with Javascript DOM traversal

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a Django widget that links a range input with a text input, synchronising the selected value from the range input in the text input. Please note I cannot use getElementById because at the time widgets are created, I do not know yet the id that will be attributed to each widget.

Initially the 2 widgets were within the same `<div>` tag, and using:

```
def __init__(self, min_value=None, max_value=None):
    widgets = (RangeInput(       attrs={'onchange':'this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.firstChild.value=this.value',#'this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value',
                                    'oninput':'this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.firstChild.value=this.value',#'this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value',
                                    'step':'any',
                                    'min':min_value,
                                    'max':max_value,
                                    'width':'400px' },),
           forms.NumberInput(attrs={'step':'any',
                                    'onchange':'this.previousElementSibling.value=this.value',
                                    'oninput':'this.previousElementSibling.value=this.value', })
           )
```

was working fine. However, I need to put the widgets within  tags

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <input type="range" [...]>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <input type="number" [...]>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my onchange and oninput JS do not work anymore. I tried this:

```
'onchange': 'this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.firstChild.value=this.value',
'oninput': 'this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.firstChild.value=this.value',
```

Unfortunately this does not work.

This is the final HTML, which does not synchronise:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <input type="range" name="form-0-value_0" value="4.51" step="any" min="0.01" onchange="this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.value=this.value" max="100" oninput="this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.value=this.value" id="id_form-0-value_0" width="400px">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <input type="number" name="form-0-value_1" value="4.51" step="any" min="0.01" onchange="this.previousElementSibling.value=this.value" max="100" oninput="this.previousElementSibling.value=this.value" id="id_form-0-value_1">
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought that parentNode should point to the `<div>` that contains the first input, then nextElementSibling should capture the next `<div>` and firstChild should point to the second input. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure the syntax is `onchange= ...` and not `onchange: ...`, then use this for the range

```
<input type="range" onchange='this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.value=this.value' min=0 max=100 value=0 oninput='this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.value=this.value'>
```

and this for the number display

```
<input type="number" value=0>
```

If you want to synchronize changes in the number field with the range add this

```
<input type="number" value=0 onchange='this.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.value=this.value' oninput='this.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.value=this.value'>
```

### Update:

**firstChild vs firstElementChild**
According to MDN, [firstChildNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) returns the first child [node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node) as an element node, a text node or a comment node (depending on which one's first) whereas [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) returns the first child node as an [element node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) (ignores text and comment nodes). The caveat being that firstElementChild *requires* a shim for IE8, IE9 and Safari. (You can find the shim [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild), scroll to end of the page)

So, in your case the whitespaces in HTML results in creation of a text node (this can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) on MDN), to quote

> Any whitespace will cause the #text node to be inserted, from a single space to any number of spaces, returns, tabs, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for our comment. Actually, the code snippet with ":" is from Django. It correctly replaces the : with a= in the final HTML code.

I have edited my original post, the HTML code is the final render, which does not work as intended.

Comment: Thank you, actually my problem was that I was using firstChild instead of firstElementChild. Any idea for the different behaviours?